# Express.js request.session.user returns undefined even though session is correctly configured

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, express-session

I'm developing a `Node.js` application using `Express.js`, and I'm encountering an issue where `request.session.user` is returning `undefined` even though I have correctly configured my session middleware. I'm looking for guidance on how to debug and resolve this issue.

I've set up my `Express.js` application with the `express-session` middleware to manage user sessions. When a user logs in, I'm storing their user data in the session object like this

```js
const loginUser= asyncErrorHandler(async (request, response, next) => {

    const { email, password } = request.body

    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password")

    //console.log(user)

    if (!user) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Invalid Email"
        })
    }


    // Compare the provided password with the stored password
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    console.log(hashPassword)

    if (!hashPassword) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Invalid Password"
        })
    }
    else {
        request.session.user = {
            id: user.id,
            email: user.email
        }
        return response.status(200).json({
            success: false,
            message: "User Login Successfully",
            data: user,
        })

    }
})
```

I can see the session object in `console.log(request.session)` and it appears to be correctly configured with the session cookie and other session options. However, when I try to access `request.session.user` in subsequent requests, it returns `undefined`.

> const isAuthenticated = asyncErrorHandler(async (request, response, next) => {
>
> console.log(request.session)
> console.log(request.session.user)
>
> if (request.session && request.session.user) {
> User is logged in
>
> next();
> else {
> User is not logged in; handle as needed (e.g., redirect to login)
> response.status(401).json({
> message: 'Unauthorized'
> })
> }
>
> })

Comment: Please post the code where you call `app.use(session({...})` and ensure it is placed before your routes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of steps that may help you solve the problem:

1. Did you configure the `express-session` middleware?
2. Did you double-check that you are using the session middleware before your route handlers. It should be included before the routes where you are trying to access `request.session.user`.
3. Ensure that your `isAuthenticated` middleware is placed after the `loginUser` middleware in your application. The order of middleware execution is important, and `isAuthenticated` should be executed after the user's session is created during login.
4. In your loginUser middleware, ensure that the session is being created and a session ID is being generated. You can check this by logging `request.session.id` after setting `request.session.user`

Comment: Yes. After setting up request.session.user i have check by console.log(request.session.user) display both id and email. But when i try to access this in another route i got request.session.user undefined.